# Generate a key in PHP for AES 256

Tags: php, key, aes

How can I securely generate a key suitable for hashing data with AES 256 using PHP?

I've tried Googling and found plenty of information about how to encrypt data using AES 256 using PHP, however all of these examples used existing pre-generated keys, wheras I need to generate the key in PHP.

Comment: Did you try to google your question? Did you come up with anything useful? Does the key need to be generated "in php", or simple be available to you. Presumably you won't be repeatedly generating new keys - or will you?

Comment: The key must be generated in php. I found nothing really helpful.

Comment: I tried to google the question and found this!

Answer (score 4):

The [`openssl-pkey-new()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) function is exactly what you are looking for.

As for the IV, you can look at [How to securely generate an IV for AES CBC Encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280769/how-to-securely-generate-an-iv-for-aes-cbc-encryption) which recommends using [`openssl-random-pseudo-bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

But if you are really looking for a helpful page, Google "Implement AES in PHP" - as the first hit you will find http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-php.html which surely will teach you everything you need to know...

Comment: Erm, that generates a PK key pair, not an aes key? Unless I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

As of php7 you can use random_bytes() function to generate cryptographically secure pseudo-random bytes.

The sources of randomness used for this function are as follows:

- On Windows, » CryptGenRandom() will always be used.
- On Linux, the » getrandom(2) syscall will be used if available.
- On other platforms, /dev/urandom will be used.
- If none of the aforementioned sources are available, then an
  Exception will be thrown

see the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) for more info

Comment: was researching openssl-random-pseudo-bytes() vs  random_bytes() and i found this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/6umjwl/random_bytes_vs_openssl_random_pseudo_bytes_which/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on a library, you can use this function on Linux/Unix machines. It is identical to `openssl-random-pseudo-bytes`:

```
<?php
$key_size = 256;  //For a 256 bit key, you can use 128 or 512 as well. 
$key = uuid_gen(($key_size / 8)); //8 bits in a byte

echo 'key length is ' .strlen($key) ."\n"; //The number of bytes

/* Returns Raw Binary */
function uuid_gen($length) {

    $fp = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');

    if ($fp !== FALSE) {
        $result .= @fread($fp, $length);
        @fclose($fp);
    } else {
        trigger_error('Can not open /dev/urandom.');
    }

    return $result;
}
```