# php ,openssl function generate random encoding , how can i correctly save encrypted text in database

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, utf-8, cryptography

Kindly I am a developer with basics of encryption , 
I have a task which is **encrypting data then save the encryption to database**, 
I am using openssl php function to encrypte and decrypte like below

```
function encrypte($stringToEncrypte){
 $method="AES-128-CBC";
    $iv=mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $pass=md5('8123jhewe8dnjsdnq');
    $encrypted=openssl_encrypt ($stringToEncrypte, $method, $pass, true , $iv);
return $encrypted."---".$iv;
}
   function decrypte($stringToDecrypte){
/*
decrypte by remove --- then get iv then get encrypted then decrypte
*/
}
```

It's working fine but the encrypted text has random encoding and this will cause many errors in saving correctly into my database which saving in **UTF-8 Encoding**.

**Definitely**, I tried to convert the encrypted key to **utf-8** by `mb_convert_encoding()` function but logically , the new encoded text will not  be decrypted correctly , because the new encoded text will not be the same of the old encoded text .

**For example**, the encrypted text  will have random  encoding like `ISO-8859-1` 
and my database encoding is **utf-8** and encoding conversion will not generate text could be decrypted again.

Comment: Do not mix mcrypt and openssl.

Comment: by using another random iv , openssl also generate random encodings .the problem is not in iv

Comment: The IV must always be 16 bytes, so traditionally it is prepended to the cipher text and the entire byte array is encoded using Base64, and the process reversed for decryption. It is unnecessary to introduce new characters as a delimiter.

Comment: I believe Charlotte's comment was about the issue of combining two different cryptographic libraries, one of which (mcrypt) is abandoned and no longer updated. Use [`random_bytes()` on PHP 7+ or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7281226/70465).

Comment: You might wanna look at [this](https://github.com/CharlotteDunois/Encryption/blob/master/encryption.class.php).

Answer (score 1):

i found something may by not very bad ,is to use [URLencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) PHP function , i tried it and it was working fine , 
but still i need experts answer

Comment: Yes, use Base64 (or hexadecimal) encoding for the resulting cipher text. Because the cipher text will have byte values ranging from `0` to `255`, it is not always easily represented in `UTF-8` encoding. To properly serialize and deserialize for decryption without data loss/corruption, you must use an encoding like Base64.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is utf8, than all your content should be utf8. You need to convert your $stringToEncrypte to utf8 **before** you encrypt it. And make shure your $pass and $iv are utf8 as well. Then you can encrypt (also utf8), save in database and decrypt everything in utf8 as well.

Comment: my string is already UTF-8 before encoding , Iam Talking About the new generated encryption and its new encoding.

Comment: What is your default encoding? It should be utf8 as well. Then it might be a problem with your database connection encoding?

Comment: yes , my default encoding is utf-8 , but when my function generating encrypted texts and detect its encoding by mb_detect_encoding($str,UTF-8) , it generates false in cases where the string isn't UTF-8.